# centOS vagrant box is not syncing the files automatically in the root folder

Tags: vagrant

I'm having centos vagrant box. Code can be found [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/VBoxes/tree/master/hadoop-learnbyexample/stand-alone).

when I do `vagrant up` for the first time, the files in the `root folder` (i.e., same folder where Vagrantfile is present) is syncing fine with the guest OS. When I add new files in the root folder later, the files are not synced with guest OS.

This is not the case when I have ubuntu based vagrant box. Ubuntu box syncs files at any point of time.

So I have to again destroy and recreate the vagrant boxes.

How can I sync the files automatically every time.

Comment: is it ordinary files or symlinks https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html#symbolic-links ?